# Similarity of new element x with the training set X

Tags: regression, modeling, nonparametric

Suppose we have trained a model (function, algorithm) $M$ which gives prediction to a new sample $x$ not observed in the training set, $M(x)$. It is natural to assume that the quality of prediction $M(x)$ depends on similarity of $x$ with the training set $X$. I wonder if there are any indices/methods which would evaluate similarity of $x$ with training set $X$, or any indices which would evaluate the quality of prediction $M(x)$. To be more specific, I don't want an overall performance of the model (which could be evaluated by RMSE, R-squared or deviance function), but I would like to estimate the quality of the prediction $M(x)$ for this particular $x$. It would be great if anyone could point me to the literature on this problem.

Comment: Predictions are often more accurate in the center of $X$ than outside its range. I.e. you could consider the distance from the center as some sort of very crude figure (look for Mahalanobis distance/leverage).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To evaluate the probability of observing some $x \in R^n$ in a data set defined by $D \in R^{i \times n}$, where $i$ is observations and $n$ is the cardinality of your features you can use density estimation/one-class classification.

While it stands to reason that there exists some relationship between the $p(x \in D$) and the quality of your prediction, you haven't observed this relationship.

What I'd recommend instead is exploring the literature on nonparametric confidence intervals. In particular, Gaussian Processes. They produce standard error estimates of your prediction and confer all of the advantages of other kernel machines at adapting to many different kinds of features.

The drawback is that they don't scale well with data size, without some hacks I've yet to master, and they are only good for regression and structured learning problems.

Gradient boosting algorithms can be adapted to produce confidence intervals, are good at classification and scale well to large datasets.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It will probably take a while for me to explore the methods you suggested. :) 
Maybe here it is ok to specify the problem I have more accurately. I actually would like to estimate the quality of GBM (gradient boosting machine) prediction. I tried to build another GBM model on the squares of the residuals (that is, if $M(x)$ was the prediction for $x$, and $y$ was the observed value, then I build another model for $(y-M(x))^2$, a variance model). This was not very successful model. Any ideas about estimating the quality of GBM prediction?

Comment: You can train GBM with a quantile loss function. Do that at the 95%, 50% and 5%?